# Bluetooth LE Advertising Packets: where to find the preamble, MAC address, and CRC?

Tags: bluetooth

Does anybody have the BLE Advertising Packet format that shows the relation (e.g. a hierarchy graph) among packet preamble, MAC address, and CRC fields? A graph that shows the length of bits for each field would be the best.

Comment: The only thing I've seen like this is a diagram that shows how the different beacon formats fit into the Bluetooth advertising packet. https://twitter.com/josryke/status/763006284052463617

Comment: Thank you. I got the cheat sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is written in the Bluetooth Core
Specification https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/ in the Link Layer chapter, section 2.1.

The advertising bluetooth device address is found in section 2.3.1.1 (ADV_IND).